# How do I make a UISegmentedControl respond only to double taps?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I am trying to make a UISegmentedControl select its segments only when detecting double taps? Any ideas on how to di this?

Answer (score 3):

It's technically possible, but why? It's a bad idea. Standard controls are standard for a reason.

Comment: +1 It's hard to imagine there isn't a better solution to your problem that will be less confusing for users.

Comment: I completely agree with you both, but it is a requirement my boss is asking of me. We are building a coloring book app and we have found that children tend to accidentally hit the segmented control that's across the bottom of the app by accident when coloring in the paint views... I was also thinking that this is probably not allowed by Apple's appstore requirements since a uisegmentedcontrol has expected behaviors, no? Anyone see a better solution?

Comment: Move the control, perhaps inside a modal popover that's called by tapping something. Perhaps instead add a confirmation dialog (though kids might not read it). A mix of the two, maybe, where a modal dialog or popover appears with one button for erasing (assuming that's what the control does) and one for leaving things as they are.

Comment: another option would be to hide the toolbar the navigation controller is on, until the screen is double tapped.

Comment: Lots of better solutions than changing this behaviour, I agree.  Can you imagine how frustrating it would be as an experienced iPhone user to find that the control "doesn't work", which is effectively how it would appear if it didn't do anything when clicked?  To answer your question however, you would have to subclass UISegmentedControl and override the event handlers; but it's a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for perspective everyone. I would like to know if it is the actual case that changing this behavior would actually violate Apple approval guidelines for the app store?

Comment: I once got a rejection because I was using a "reply" button icon, but the button action was a bit different than "reply," and I had to use a different icon. So they really do scrutinize your UI.

Comment: As for children using the control accidentally, it's a great insight, but making the control harder to use is a wrong solution. It's hard for children to understand abstract concepts like double tap, so you're just guaranteeing that they will never use it. Maybe that's what you want. If not, you'd be better off by rethinking what widget to use. I don't know enough about your app to recommend a solution, and it becomes a design question rather than coding question.

Comment: Yea that all makes sense. It really is a design issue for my employer. Thanks again.